# Compare a specific array element to a string with "if" in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char, if-statement

Rather Trivial Question.

So I tried to do this:

```
if (array[0]=="some_string")
```

where `array` is a list of strings

```
array[0] = "some_string_1";
array[1] = "some_string_2";
array[2] = "some_string_3";
```

but obviously it doesn't work...
What do I have to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if(array[0] == 'n')
```

> `""` signifies `string`
>   `''` signifies `char`

Note: `'a'` is a `char` and `"a"` is a `string`, so `'a' != "a"`

`char` is a single character (actually int), so if you want to compare strings, use `strcmp` instead.

Comment: " " actually signifies char*, but you're still right otherwise.

Comment: ..But you can only use strcmp() if the string is null-terminated, or if you know the array size of both strings to exceed a length n-1, you can us strncmp().

Comment: @San: i cant explain everything in detail here :)

Answer (score 0):

in the example you give, you are comparing a single character (array[0]) with the address of a compiled-in string ("some_string").

Because a string literal is treated as a null-terminated character array, and comparisons against a character array with the == operator compare the address of the array.

The example you gave is essentially similar to this:

```
char* x = "some_string";
char array[10];
if(array[0] == x)
    ...
```

And you can see from this example that the types simply don't match. As another poster stated, you use the [] operator to obtain a specific character from the offset in the brackets from the start of the array.